# C++ Stem and Leaf Plot. I don't understand how to make a linked list of linked lists

Tags: c++

I have a project making a stem and leaf plot with linked lists and I keep getting errors that I don't even understand. How do you make a linked list of linked lists? I have to do it this way for the assignment so I can't do it in an alternate way and I have to work from the files below. My top stem linked list works, but it doesn't seem to be accessing the leaf portion and I'm getting the following error:

"The instruction at 0x0000000000404050 referenced at 0x000000000000001E. The memory could not be read."

Here is my code:

```
* Driver.cpp
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#include "StemAndLeaf2.h"

int main()
{

 ifstream fin("input.txt");

 int x;
 unsigned short leafunit, stemunit;

 fin >> leafunit >> stemunit;

 StemAndLeaf one;
 one.setLeafUnit(leafunit);
 one.setStemUnit(stemunit);

 while (fin >> x)
 {
   one.addTerm(x);
   cout << "Insert: " << x << endl;
   cout << "StemAndLeafPlot: " << endl;
   cout << one << endl;
 }

 cout << "The smallest term: " << one.getSmallestTerm() << endl;
 cout << "The largest term: " << one.getLargestTerm() << endl;
 
   return 0;
}
```

```
/*
* SteamAndLeaf2.h
*/

#ifndef STEAMANDLEAF2_H_
#define STEAMANDLEAF2_H_

#include <math.h>
#include <list>
#include <ostream>
// DO NOT REMOVE THE LINE BELOW
/* CMSC341_TEST_INCLUDES */

#include "Stem2.h"

class StemAndLeaf
{
   // DO NOT REMOVE THE LINE BELOW
   /* CMSC341_FRIEND_CLASSES */
public:
   StemAndLeaf(){FRONT_ptr = NULL; REAR_ptr = NULL;};
   ~StemAndLeaf()
   {
       while(FRONT_ptr != NULL)
       {
           Cursor = FRONT_ptr;
           FRONT_ptr = Cursor->getNext();
           delete Cursor;
       }
   }

   unsigned short getLeafUnit() const { return leafUnit; }
   void setLeafUnit(unsigned short leafUnit) { this->leafUnit = leafUnit; }
   unsigned short getStemUnit() const { return stemUnit; }
   void setStemUnit(unsigned short stemUnit) { this->stemUnit = stemUnit; }

   /**
    * @brief Get the smallest term in the datastructure. The term MUST be reconstructed
    *
    * @return unsigned short
    */
   unsigned short getSmallestTerm() const
   {
       return ((FRONT_ptr->getValue()*10))+(FRONT_ptr->findSmallestValue()));
   }

   /**
    * @brief Get the largest term in the datastructure. The term MUST be reconstructed
    *
    * @return unsigned short
    */
   unsigned short getLargestTerm() const
   {
       return ((REAR_ptr->getValue()*10))+(REAR_ptr->findLargestValue()));
   }


   /**
    * @brief Adds the term to the data structure. Insertion MUST be ordered, both for Stem and the Leaf
    *
    * @param term the value to add
    */
   void addTerm(unsigned short term)
   {
       Insert = new Stem();
       Insert->setValue(term/10);
       Insert->setLeafList(Insert->getLeafLink());
       if(isEmpty())
       {
           Insert->setLeafCount(1);
           Insert->insert(term%10);
           FRONT_ptr = Insert;
           REAR_ptr = Insert;
       }
       else
       {
           for(Cursor = FRONT_ptr; Cursor != NULL; Prev = Cursor, Cursor = Cursor->getNext())
           {
               Insert->setLeafCount(1);
               Insert->insert(term%10);
               if((Cursor == FRONT_ptr) && (Cursor->getValue() > Insert->getValue()))
               {
                   Insert->setNext(Cursor);
                   FRONT_ptr = Insert;
               }
               else if((Cursor == REAR_ptr) && (Cursor->getValue() < Insert->getValue()))
               {
                   Cursor->setNext(Insert);
                   REAR_ptr = Insert;
               }
               else if((Prev->getValue() < Insert->getValue()) && (Cursor->getValue() > Insert->getValue()))
               {
                   Prev->setNext(Insert);
                   Insert->setNext(Cursor);
               }
               else if(Insert->getValue() == Cursor->getValue())
               {
                   if(!Cursor->insert(term%10))
                   {
                       Cursor->incrementLeafCount();
                   }
               }
               break;
           }
       }
   }

   /*
    * Used to display/debug the StemAndLeaf diagram
    * will look exactly like this (using example in project):
    *
    * 0 | 0:1
    * ...
    * 2 |
    * 3 | 6:2 9:1
    *
    * You will not be given too much data to overrun 80 characters
    */
   friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const StemAndLeaf &x)//;
   {
       out << x.FRONT_ptr->getValue() << " | ";
       return out;
   }

private:
   unsigned short leafUnit; // increment of each leaf in this particular structure
   unsigned short stemUnit; // increment of each stem in this particular structure

   Stem *FRONT_ptr, *REAR_ptr, *Insert, *Prev, *Cursor;

   inline bool isEmpty() const { return FRONT_ptr == nullptr; }

};
#endif /* STEAMANDLEAF2_H_ */
```

```
/*
 * Steam2.h
 */
#ifndef STEM2_H_
#define STEM2_H_
#include <ostream>
#include <list>
// DO NOT REMOVE THE LINE BELOW
/* CMSC341_TEST_INCLUDES */

#include "Leaf2.h"

class Stem
{
    // DO NOT REMOVE THE LINE BELOW
    /* CMSC341_FRIEND_CLASSES */

public:
    Stem(){FRONT_ptr = NULL; REAR_ptr = NULL;}
    virtual ~Stem(){};

    unsigned short getLeafCount() const { return m_LeafCount; }
    void setLeafCount(unsigned short LeafCount) { m_LeafCount = LeafCount; }
    void incrementLeafCount() { m_LeafCount++; }
    void decrementLeafCount() { m_LeafCount--; }

    Leaf *getLeafLink() const {return FRONT_ptr;}
    void setLeafList(Leaf *LeafList) { FRONT_ptr = LeafList; }

    unsigned short getValue() const { return m_Value; }
    void setValue(unsigned short value) { m_Value = value; }

    Stem *getNext() const { return m_Next; }
    void setNext(Stem *next) { m_Next = next; }

    /**
     * @brief Add the value to the stem. Returns trues if a new lef was created
     *
     * @param value The number to insert
     * @return true if a new leaf was created
     * @return false if we've seen the value before
     */
    bool insert(unsigned short value)
    {
        Insert = new Leaf();
        Insert->setValue(value);
        if(FRONT_ptr = NULL)
        {
            FRONT_ptr = Insert;
            REAR_ptr = Insert;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            for(Cursor = FRONT_ptr; Cursor != NULL; Prev = Cursor, Cursor = Cursor->getNext())
            {
                if(Cursor->getValue() == Insert->getValue())
                {
                    Cursor->incrementCount();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if((Cursor == FRONT_ptr) && (Cursor->getValue() > Insert->getValue()))
                    {
                        Insert->setNext(Cursor);
                        FRONT_ptr = Insert;
                    }
                    else if((Cursor == REAR_ptr) && (Cursor->getValue() < Insert->getValue()))
                    {
                        Cursor->setNext(Insert);
                        REAR_ptr = Insert;
                    }
                    else if((Prev->getValue() < Insert->getValue()) && (Cursor->getValue() > Insert->getValue()))
                    {
                        Prev->setNext(Insert);
                        Insert->setNext(Cursor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    unsigned short findSmallestValue()
    {
        if(FRONT_ptr != NULL){
        return FRONT_ptr->getValue();}
        else {return 0;}
    }
    unsigned short findLargestValue()
    {
        if(REAR_ptr != NULL){
        return REAR_ptr->getValue();}
        else {return 0;}
    }

private:
    // they are given the code for a L.L.
    Leaf *FRONT_ptr, *REAR_ptr, *Insert, *Prev, *Cursor;

    /**
     * Stem Value
     */
    unsigned short m_Value;

    /**
     * How many leaves in this stem
     */
    unsigned short m_LeafCount;

    /**
     * Pointer to the next stem
     */
    Stem *m_Next;
};
#endif /* STEM2_H_ */
```

```
/*
*Leaf2.h
*/

#ifndef LEAF2_H_
#define LEAF2_H_

#include <ostream>
// DO NOT REMOVE THE LINE BELOW
/* CMSC341_TEST_INCLUDES */


struct Leaf
{
    // DO NOT REMOVE THE LINE BELOW
    /* CMSC341_FRIEND_CLASSES */

    Leaf()
        : m_Count(1)
    {
    }

    unsigned short getValue() const { return m_Value; }
    void setValue(unsigned short value) { m_Value = value; }

    unsigned short getCount() const { return m_Count; }
    void setCount(unsigned short count) { m_Count = count; }
    void incrementCount() { m_Count++; }
    void decrementCount() { m_Count--; }

    Leaf *getNext() const { return m_Next; }
    void setNext(Leaf *next) { m_Next = next; }

    /**
     * @brief Operator overload to print the Leaf in a nice format According to
     * the project description the format should be "value:count"
     *
     * @param out
     * @param leaf
     * @return std::ostream&
     */
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Leaf &leaf)
    {
        out << leaf.m_Value << ":" << leaf.m_Count;
        return out;
    }

private:
    unsigned short m_Value;
    unsigned short m_Count;
    Leaf *m_Next;
};
#endif /* LEAF2_H_ */
```

The input file is a .txt file with the following values:

```
1
10
22
13
8
23
```

I get the error even if I turn everything after the "add term" call into a comment, and I know the leaf portion isn't working because when I run the "findSmallestTerm" and "findLargestTerm" it only gives me the stem value. There's a lot wrong with my code beyond just the error with the leaf values but I'm not asking for the answer to the whole project, I just need help on getting the stem and leaf lists to connect, if that makes sense. Sorry to just dump all of the code here, but I don't know which part of it is the problem so I didn't know what would be relevant or not.

UPDATE: I deleted some of the unnecessary code and added the info for the input file.

Comment: 0x000000000000001E is likely a null pointer plus a small offset. Inspect all of your list iteration code and make sure you're checking for and respecting the end of the the list. One thing you can do to speed the search is run the code under a debugger, wait for the program to halt because of the crash, and then follow the backtrace until you find the source of the null pointer.

Comment: It is really, really hard to know what is relevant when you don't know what the bug is. You don't want to add all of the code, that would get the question closed almost instantly, so you need to find a way to isolate the error in a smaller code example. [mre] describes a technique for doing this. The true beauty of producing an example that isolates the bug is it almost always reduces the problem to the point that the bug is unmissable and easily fixed, eliminating the need for the question. This example can be a hard thing to make, but totally worth it.

Comment: And don't ignore the compiler warnings. Most compilers will flag trivial little typos like `if(FRONT_ptr = NULL)` for you. You want `if(FRONT_ptr == NULL)` otherwise the program assigns `NULL` to `FRONT_ptr`, obliterating the list, and then tests if `FRONT_ptr`  is non-zero. Which it now can't be.

Comment: Interesting side note: `getSmallestTerm` and its friends are fatal if used on an empty list. You need to test `FRONT_ptr` for NULL before you can safely `FRONT_ptr->getValue()`

Comment: Add to that, we also have no idea what the input data is. That should also be included as part of a proper [mcve], either by a separate list in the question or better still directly declared static in the code itself (as if you were writing a unit tests, itself an outstanding idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is caused by uninitialized data members and wrong check statements:

```cpp
if(FRONT_ptr = NULL)
```

This should be:

```cpp
if(FRONT_ptr == NULL)
```

Stem::m_Next should be inited:

```cpp
Stem *m_Next=NULL;
```

Stem::m_Next should be inited:

```cpp
Leaf *m_Next=NULL;
```

The variable `Prev` should be inited after entering the for loop:

```cpp
void addTerm(unsigned short term) {
    // Prev should be inited or the crash happens
    for (Prev = Cursor, Cursor = FRONT_ptr; Cursor != NULL;
         Prev = Cursor, Cursor = Cursor->getNext()) {
}
}
```

The Stem class should have destructors to avoid memory leak:

```cpp
virtual ~Stem() {
  while (FRONT_ptr != NULL) {
    Cursor = FRONT_ptr;
    FRONT_ptr = Cursor->getNext();
    delete Cursor;
  }
};
```

The code also have other some bad smell and bugs:

- Temporary variables should not be data members: INsert, Prev, Cursor
- `Stem::Insert`, `StemAndLeaf::Insert` have memory leaks when the data have existed in the list, the new elements haven't been inserted into the list, the pointer should be deleted
- Forget to check if pointer is NULL before accessing it: `getSmallestTerm`, `getLargestTerm`